# Harmon.ie Sidebar is open but blank

Tags: harmon.ie

New install of Outlook 2016 Click-To-Run for O365.  Verified .net 4.72 framework installed.  Harmon installs and I can interact with the ribbon buttons to include setting up my site; however, sidebar is blank.  The sidebar opens, but it doesn't display anything.  Haromon.ie was downloaded just before install - so latest version.

The only thing in the logs that looks related is:
com.mainsoft.sharepoint.sidebar.SideBarViewPart - External tabs provider was not found

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Answer (score 1):

Open Outlook settings, choose "Optimize for compatibility" option, restart Outlook

---- Jean